# Get date from table and display on datetime picker

Tags: c#, database, get, datepicker

I have a table that contains datetime fields, i want to retrieve that date and display it on a datetime picker on c#, how can i achieve this?

```
reader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();
DTPicker.Value += reader[1];
reader.Close();
```

the date is on my second column of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to read data from a OleDbDataReader:

```
private static void ReadData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders";
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        OracleDataReader reader;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Always call Read before accessing data. 
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + reader.GetString(1));
        }

        // Always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

[OleDbDataReader.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Instead of using `reader.GetInt(0)` you would then use `Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0])`

Comment: "DTPicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[2]);"

worked perfectly thx@Bart va der Drift